# RadioButton doesn't "receive" focus

Tags: javascript, asp.net, focus, radio-button

I've pieced together some code to use in ASP.NET to prevent controls from losing focus on postback so a tab OR click of another control saves the users position and returns it.

In Page_Load I have the following:

```
PartNum_tb.Attributes["onfocus"] = "gotFocus(this)";
Department_tb.Attributes["onfocus"] = "gotFocus(this)";
PartWeight_tb.Attributes["onfocus"] = "gotFocus(this)";
Standard_rb.Attributes.Add("onfocus","gotFocus(this)");
Special_rb.Attributes.Add("onfocus","gotFocus(this)");

if (Page.IsPostBack)
   Page.SetFocus(tabSelected.Value);
```

This is my Javascript (tabSelected is a hidden field):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gotFocus(control) {
        document.getElementById('form1').tabSelected.value = control.id;

        if (control.type == "text") {
            if (control.createTextRange) {
                //IE  
                var FieldRange = control.createTextRange();
                FieldRange.moveStart('character', control.value.length);
                FieldRange.collapse();
                FieldRange.select();
            }
            else {
                //Firefox and Opera  
                control.focus();
                var length = control.value.length;
                control.setSelectionRange(length, length);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is when I tab or click onto one of the radio buttons, it returns focus to whatever the last control was instead which is unintuitive and confusing to a user. It does this because the RadioButton never gets focus, therefore the cursor position doesn't get updated. After extensive Google searching it appears that its **not really possible to know when a RadioButton *gains* focus**. Is there *any* solution known to even just work around this problem?

Comment: To clarify: The reason this happens is because the Attributes.Add("onfocus") for the two RadioButtons above is basically useless. It does nothing and never gets called.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the problem is offhand, but the first thing that comes to mind is to try trapping "onclick" instead of "onfocus" for your radio buttons, where the "onclick" would still call your "gotFocus()" function (and you'd continue to use "onfocus" for your other elements).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "onclick" works only if I click on the selected radio button. If i click an unselected one first, OR am tabbing through the form (which is probably what the user will be doing) the focus still hops back to the previous control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution may be adding a `keypress` event to the previous field and use the `click` event on the radios. Also, move the `control.focus();` out of the `if` statement:

**Javascript**

```
function changeFocus(next) {
    gotFocus(next);
}

function gotFocus(control) { 
    document.getElementById('form1').tabSelected.value = control.id; 
    control.focus();

    if (control.type == "text") { 
        if (control.createTextRange) { 
            //IE   
            var FieldRange = control.createTextRange(); 
            FieldRange.moveStart('character', control.value.length); 
            FieldRange.collapse(); 
            FieldRange.select(); 
        } 
        else { 
            //Firefox and Opera   
            var length = control.value.length; 
            control.setSelectionRange(length, length); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I decided to go in a totally different direction and just keep my controls from posting back and causing this problem in the first place. The solution feels like such a hack but I think you are right this is about the only way this can be done. Thanks for the response. (bounty in 50min)